# Getting each foreach loop in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, social-networking

I'm currently looking at making a social media style site.

I have a foreach displaying a sql table of user posts.

I've looked and found how to submit to a php file without refreshing but now I'm in need of a way to have the ability to like each individual post.

Currently, if I put the ajax script at say the bottom, it likes the last post within the foreach loop. Any suggestions on how I can have it "like" the correct post? Hopefully this explains enough.

My ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {postid, $postid},
        success: function(data){
            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example have a button for every post and you add onclick event that call the function and passing the post id as function parameters.

So your function will look like something

```js
function likePost(postid){
  try{
    
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "get_data.php",
        data:{"postid": postid},
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data);       
    }
      });

 
  }
  catch(e){
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was after, thank you for the help!